# Grab Cell dynamically based on row and column string

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variables

I have a table with months across columns. The months are always shifting so I am trying to adapt my code to accommodate this. It works great if the column remain static,I just need to figure out how to find which column is the total column dynamically.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub CalculateTotalGP()

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.count, 27).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, 27)
            If .Value = "GP%" Then
            Range("AL" & RowToTest & ":AL" & RowToTest).Formula = "=SUMIFS(AL:AL,AA:AA,""GrossProfit Total"")/SUMIFS(AL:AL,AA:AA,""Income Total"")"
        End If
            End If
        End With
Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

What I need to grab in order to replace *"AL"* everywhere with a variable:

```
InStr(1, Cells(6, i), "Total")
```

Basically no matter where the total columns is in the specified range, input that formula. The only thing that remains static is my column range, 16 columns from AD8 to AS9999(or N) and my criteria from column AA.

Can you help me figure this out?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Are you trying to find a cell by value? Are you trying to find a cell by a range expression? I don't get it

Comment: I am trying to find a cell by a row and a column. So if "GP%" is on AA10 and "Total" is on AL6 then I need AL10. AA Rows(GP, Efficiency, etc). Columns across AD:AS(May, Jun, July, etc., Total). I am trying to find the cell by x row and y column and input my formula there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the column number for header "Total" use the GetHeaderCol() function (instead of Match)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestHeader()
    Dim tHeader As Long

    tHeader = GetHeaderCol(Sheet1, "Total", 6)  'If "Total" in row 6 & col H, result -> 8

    If tHeader > 0 Then Debug.Print "Total column: " & tHeader
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetHeaderCol(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal hdr As String, _
                             Optional ByVal hdrRow As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim hdrs As Variant, c As Variant

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    hdrRow = IIf(hdrRow = 0, 1, Abs(hdrRow))
    hdrs = ws.Range(ws.Cells(hdrRow, 1), ws.Cells(hdrRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    If Not IsEmpty(hdrs) Then
        For c = 1 To UBound(hdrs, 2)
            If InStr(1, hdrs(1, c), hdr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                GetHeaderCol = c
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
    GetHeaderCol = 0
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Paul. Thank for the help. However I am unable to adapt it to my example. Can you please help me with that? Basically I am trying to input something at the intersection of a row that contains x and a column that contains y.

Comment: Hey Paul, I have managed to figure it out using what you have provided. Thank you for your contribution to this community. Cheers!

Comment: @iCosmin: sorry for the late reply - I'm glad you worked it out